# Using observe function in shiny R

Tags: javascript, r, variables, shiny, observers

I am trying to send the value of a JavaScript variable from **ui.R** to **Server.R** whenever it is changed. 
When a user clicks on a link, its href value is alerted . Till here it works fine. 
The links are of the form

```
<a href="something.com" onclick=\"clickFunction(this.href); return false;\" target=\"_blank\">Sample link </a>
```

Now, the href value is stored in variable `link` in **ui.R** . 
I am sending the value of link to **server.R** using **Shiny.onInputChange** function.

But the observe function in **server.R** is not giving me any value. Please tell me how to do this by using observe function or any other way if possible.

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$script(HTML("
                      function clickFunction(link){
                          alert(link); 
                          Shiny.onInputChange(\"linkClicked\",link);   
                      }
                     "))

//rest of the code which is not related

)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    input$linkClicked
    print(input$linkClicked)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't really fully understand where the link is coming from and how the app looks since you didn't provide enough code (for example: what does it mean "variable in the UI"?). But here's a small example that shows how the javascript sends info to the server successfully.  I'm using the shinyjs package which is a package I wrote.

```
library(shinyjs)
jscode <- "
shinyjs.clickfunc = function(link) {
  alert(link);  
  Shiny.onInputChange('linkClicked', link);
}"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
    textInput("link", ""),
    actionButton("btn", "submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      js$clickfunc(input$link)
    })
    observe({
      input$linkClicked
      print(input$linkClicked)
    })
  }
))
```

**EDIT**:

If I understand correctly how the links are generated, this works

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$script(HTML("
                      function clickFunction(link){
                          alert(link); 
                          Shiny.onInputChange('linkClicked',link);   
                      }
                     ")),
    tags$a(href="www.google.com", onclick="clickFunction('rstudio.org'); return false;", "click me")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      input$linkClicked
      print(input$linkClicked)
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Please see I added the information on how the link variable is generated.  @daattali

Comment: still not totally clear. There's no actual `link` variable. Are you just using tags$a(...) in the ui? Would really help if you provide an example that we can run

Comment: Actually the links are generated from web scraping. And, when a link is clicked, the onclick function send the value of href to clickFunc(link), hence link is the argument of the clickFunc function. alert(link) is working means the value of link exists.

Comment: in the server, what is input$btn ? And also, what is js$clickfunc ? Are they package functions? if yes do they track click event? please elaborate on the code. :)

Comment: Almost. This goes back to the problem that I don't know what your actual original code looks like (are you using tags$a like I did?). I'm assuming that our code is very similar but you don't have the "return false", which causes the app to go to a different url and have a big "NOT FOUND" after clicking the button

Comment: If this isn't what you want, then please post a reproducible shiny app that shows what happens and what you expect to happen, otherwise it's hard to know exactly what you want :)

Comment: Adding return false ; stops the link from opening in new tab.

Comment: oh geez seems like I really don't have what you wanted. I'd say you should show more sample code, and show where the `link` variable is, sorry :/