# is there any R way to create as the attached GIF?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to create a table with images in header row, each image is a hyperlink to another landing page with popover once mouse rollover it. 
I need to make the 1st column in each row contains text also hyperlinked to a new landing page.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) and based on Brandon Bertelsen's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671958/how-to-embed-an-image-in-a-cell-a-table-using-dt-r-and-shiny)

```
dat <- data.frame(
  `<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png" height="52" title="China"></img></a>` = c('1234','23456'), 
   check.names = FALSE, 
   row.names = c('<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_domestic_product">GDP</a>', "Population"))

DT::datatable(dat, escape = FALSE)
```

[image]

See [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-image-link.html) for more info about creating HTML Image Link and HTML text link.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I've  tried this but it's not working,

Comment: @AhmedBaghdadi to get a nice cell's format check https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html but you may need to transpose your dataframe. Or you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784955/r-formatting-by-row-using-dt

Comment: and how can i add pop over on the flag to mention "China" before clicking ?

Comment: @AhmedBaghdadi add `title="China"` after the height attribute inside the _img_ tag. see my update.

Comment: If this answer is ok for you, you can mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: Dear @A.Suliman, could you support with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375480/using-observe-function-in-shiny-r

Comment: @AhmedGondy I'll be happy to help but please open a new question "[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable)" and linked to alloyeduniv's question if it helps to provide the context or add additional information.